# Are the "Prototype pattern" and the "Virtual constructor" the same patterns?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

Does the Virtual constructor - implementing `virtual function clone()`:

```
class X {
public:
     virtual X* clone() {
         return new X(*this);
     }
};
```

mean the same concept as the Prototype design pattern?

Comment: Not exactly. Cloning interfaces are necessary to implement the _Prototype Design Pattern_.

Comment: Thank you. But what additional meaning does the Prototype pattern have then?

Comment: That you create new class instances using a configurable _Factory_, which uses a single instance as prototype to clone from. You can see a more in depth explanation [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... mean the same concept as the Prototype design pattern?

No, it doesn't. The *cloneable interface* is only part of the implementation of the [*Prototype Design Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype).

The point of *Prototype* is to have a [*Factory*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) to hold instances of prototypical instances, and knows which to use as cloning source to create new instances.